# Why does my text look so bad in my ios App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

I have a uiscrollview that has a custom child view that contains text and images.
The text items are UILabels.  I have attached an image representing the quality issue:

[image]

Do you guys think it might be worth a shot to draw the text, then convert to a uiimage and display that instead? Maybe it would scale better? Or perhaps there is a way to smooth the text?

Comment: Is the image scaled?  That looks really, really small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done now is I have created a uiimage version of my text and am showing that now instead of the uilabels, the quality is soo much better, you can really see the difference when you are looking at it scaled up on the ipad, it must just do a better job scaling images then text?

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

The above images show how the text renders on the ipad with my app scaled up, before and after my change.

Comment: Is this the answer to your original question?  If so, please "accept" it.  If this is not an answer, please delete it and add it to your original post.

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason to expect that you're going to draw the text better than `UILabel` does. Your picture is very hard to make out, but here's what you want to look at:

- Are you just adding a `UILabel` to the `UIScrollView`'s `contentView`, or are you doing something else fancier. That "something else fancier" could easily be the problem.
- Make sure you're drawing on pixel-aligned boundaries. The easiest way is to make sure the `origin` of your `UILabel` is integral (not a fraction). On a retina display, you can get away with half-points, but it's usually easier just to make everything integers.

Comment: +1 for pixel-aligned boundaries. Your bounds can often be unaligned if you use math to calculate your target rect (`frame.origin.x = bounds.size.width/2` for example). You can easily deal with this situation by running your computed rect through `CGRectIntegral()`.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it is the position issue. I bet you set the x or y value to float value like 12.3 or 12.5 .

Comment: I am only setting my position on int values.  No partial pixels.